# Restriction of variables in R

Tags: r, function, plot

I want to plot the following function:
`D=(x^p +y^p)^(1/p)`,

but i want to restrict x and y such that: `x + y = 1`, `0 <= x <= 1`,`0 <= y <= 1`. I'm not really sure how to place these restrictions though.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
require(lattice)

p<-0.1

dp<-function(x,y,p){
  (x^p +y^p)^{1/p}
}

x<-y<- seq(0,1, length=100)
Z<-outer(x,y,dp)

newcols <- colorRampPalette(c("pink","maroon", "red"))

plot1<-wireframe(Z,drape=T,col.regions=newcols(100)  ,screen = list(z =  75, x = -90, y = -60))
```

but i want it so that the function is undefined for values of x,y such that x+y is not equal to 1.

**update**: Just to clarify, I want the function to only take values from the set that contains the elements (x,y,z) such that 0 <=z<=1, 0 <=x<=1, 0 <=y<=1, AND x+y+z =1. So something like:

```
p<-0.1

    dp<-function(x,y,p){
      (x^p +y^p + (1-x-y)^p)^{1/p}
    }

    x<-y<- seq(0,1, length=100)
    Z<-outer(x,y,dp)

    newcols <- colorRampPalette(c("pink","maroon", "red"))

    plot1<-wireframe(Z,drape=T,col.regions=newcols(100)  ,screen = list(z =  75, x = -90, y = -60))
```

The function should NOT be defined unless all the elments add up to one

Comment: The constraint x + y = 1 produces a line in 3d, not a plane, so why would you want to use `wireframe`? Is this a typo? Also I assume the remaining constraints are `0 <= x <= 1` and `0 <= y <= 1` rather than `0 <= x` and `y <= 1` which it looks like in the present formulation.

Comment: I think that `Z<-outer(x,y,dp)` should be `Z<-outer(x,y,dp,p)` (else I obtain an error `Error in FUN(X, Y, ...) : argument "p" is missing, with no default`).

Comment: @Backlin What im trying to plot is the function: ( sum_i=1^n x_i^p)^(1/p) where x_i are all non negative, and sum x_i = 1 (in other words, x_i belongs to the unit simplex), should i be taking a third argument then to have it in a 3d plot? ie
 dp<-function(x,y,p){
  (x^p +y^p+(1-x-y)^p)^{1/p}
}

Comment: Sorry, this might sound silly, but why don't you do something like: `x<-seq(0,1,length=100)`, and `y=1-x`? All your restrictions are satisfied then. Do you have to show that the `dp` function outputs `undefined` when `x + y != 1`?

Comment: @RHertel of course not :) This is not a competition :)

Comment: @RHertel sorry, maybe i didn't word the question clearly, I've updated now

Comment: The additional condition `x+y+z =1` in your edit requires the solution of your equation; a task that goes far beyond the original question. Moreover, the limit where z is not larger than 1 in your case is very narrow; near a range of x*y=0 (i.e. x very close or equal to zero and/or y almost or equal to zero).

Comment: @RHertel maybe a more appropriate question wouldve been, given this function, what is the best way to depict it graphically in 3 dimensions

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps:

```
p<-0.1
dp <-function(x,y,p){  (x^p +y^p)^{1/p} }
x<-seq(0,1, length=100)
Z <- outer(x,x,dp,p)
Z[col(Z)+row(Z)>ncol(Z)] <- NA # remove the entries in the upper triangle of the square matrix
newcols <- colorRampPalette(c("pink","maroon", "red"))
plot1<-wireframe(Z,drape=T,col.regions=newcols(100), screen = list(z =  75, x = -90, y = 80))
```

[image]

We only need one sequence, `x`, since `y` has the same range, [0,1]. In order to select only those values where `x+y<=1` we can take the matrix created by `outer` and set all the values in the upper triangle to `NA`.